# radcombox's Item is binding perfectly but not displaying all on first click

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I am using telerik radcombobox in my project.Let me show you its mark up first..

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbx_AltUoM" runat="server" Width="100%" Filter="Contains" MarkFirstMatch="true" AutoPostBack="False"
OnClientDropDownOpening="onUoMComboItemRequesting"> </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Now when I am clicking on the combobox its showing this:

[image]

But while I am clicking on the lower arrow of the pane , its showing all item.

Now second time when I am clicking, it's showing all items..

[image]

Could anybody tell me why this is happening here?Please, I need help :)

Edit : while inspecting I got this (while clicking first time)

```
<div id="ctl05_rw_UoMGroupDetails_C_rgv_UoMDetails_ctl05_rw_UoMGroupDetails_C_rgv_UoMDetails_ctl00_AltUoMID_cmbx_AltUoM_DropDown" class="RadComboBoxDropDown RadComboBoxDropDown_Office2010Blue " style="width: 105px; display: block; top: 0px; visibility: visible; transition: none;">
```

***div class="rcbScroll rcbWidth" style="height: 21px; this causing problem, I need to remove height attribute from here..***

Answer (score 0):

you will add the class .rcbScroll rcbWidth in head style tag to set the height attribute.

```
.rcbScroll .rcbWidth
{
height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: setting height="100%" solve my problem :) btw thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting Height = "100%" fix my problem :)